# Select lowest ID and calculate deviation from the lowest

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to create a view. I have some data in my SQL Server database, and I want to order them by their `mark1` and `mark2`. Now when I sort them I want to select the `mark1` who has the lowest `mark2` and calculate what's the deviation from other `mark1`s.
The table is looking right now like this, but without deviation.

```
|   mark1    |    mark2    |      mass    ||    deviation |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:||:------------:|
| 0001       |      10000  |     10,0     ||    min0001   |
| 0001       |      15000  |     12,0     ||    +20%      |
| 0002       |      11200  |     18,0     ||    min0002   |
| 0002       |      13000  |     35,5     ||    +97.2%    |
| 0002       |      14565  |     85,5     ||    375%      |
| 0003       |      15004  |     15,4     ||    min0003   |
| 0003       |      21250  |     17,4     ||    +12.9%    |
| 0003       |      60764  |     16,4     ||    6.49%     |
```

And now, as you see it's ordered by `mark1` and `mark2`.
Now, my problem is the deviation column, I need it to take `mark1`, Let's say `0001` (his `mark2` is `10000`) and find the lowest mass and find the deviation from other `0001` (`15000`). As you can see the in the table.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? The newer versions have some functions that would make this much easier.

Comment: SQL 2014 version...I hope it helps...

Comment: Do you want to compare with the lowest mass or with the mass of the lowest mark2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[FIRST_VALUE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx)

> Returns the first value in an ordered set of values in SQL Server
>   2014.

Partition on `mark1` and order by `mark2`.

Something like this should do it for you:

```
select T.*,
       100 * (T.mass - T.FirstMass) / T.FirstMass as Deviation
from (
     select T.*,
            first_value(T.mass) over(partition by T.mark1 order by T.mark2) as FirstMass
     from dbo.YourTable as T    
     ) as T;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17c07d/1)

Comment: Mikael beat me to it :)

Comment: Yes, realized it and removed my comment ;) The data and wording suggest your solution (except for that "lowest mass", they need to clarify.)

Comment: @ypercube what comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will give the results:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (t.mass / MIN(mass) OVER (PARTITION BY mark1) - 1) * 100 AS devValue,
    CASE 
        WHEN t.mass = MIN(mass) OVER (PARTITION BY mark1) THEN 'min' + mark1 
        ELSE 
            CASE 
                WHEN t.mass > MIN(mass) OVER (PARTITION BY mark1) THEN '+'
                ELSE '-' 
            END +
            CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), (t.mass / MIN(mass) OVER (PARTITION BY mark1) - 1) * 100)) + '%'
     END AS deviation
FROM
    t
ORDER BY
    t.mark1, t.mark2
```